# Is there an equivalent of the WriteRequestBatch class for the DynamoDB Javascript SDK?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I came across the [WriteRequestBatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.WriteRequestBatch.html) class in the AWS PHP SDK. I haven't been able to find a class by that name in the Javascript SDK, so I'm wondering if there is an equivalent?

I already use [batchWrite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property), but still sometimes get unprocessed items due to throttling. It looks like the WriteRequestBatch class makes sure *all* items get processed successfully, unless I'm mistaken and it functions just like batchWrite.